# How to parse json with unknown key by Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, parsing, retrofit

I want to parse this JSON by Retrofit (i don't know field names{xxx,yyy,zzz}) 
I tried some Maps, but I did something wrong.
Please help me parse this damn json

```
    {
        xxx: [
        {
        name: "name1",
        description: "desc1"
        }
        ],
        yyy: [
        {
        name: "name2",
        description: "desc2"
        }
        ],
        zzz: [
        {
        name: "name3",
        description: "desc3"
        },
{
        name: "name4",
        description: "desc4"
        }
        ]
        }
```

---Solution---

I tried create class responce, but it wrong way

```
public class DishesCategoryResponse {
    public Map<String, List<Dish>> settingsMap;
}
```

Then i tried this and it works

```
@GET("/api/restaurant_menu/{id}")
    Observable<Map<String, List<Dish>>> getDishesCategory(@Path("id") long id);
```

Answer (score 2):

One day I had a similar task. Ain't sure my solution is perfect, but it may help you.

I had this json file:

[image: Json screenshot]

```
final JSONObject bodyObject = new JSONObject(body);
final JSONObject activities = bodyObject.getJSONObject("activities");
final Iterator<String> keys = activities.keys(); // you can iterate through all keys

final List<ContactActivity> contactActivityInfoList = new ArrayList<ContactActivity>();

while (keys.hasNext()) {
    final String key = keys.next();

    final String jsonString = activities.getJSONObject(key).toString();
    final ContactActivity contactActivity =
                mGson.fromJson(jsonString, ContactActivity.class);

    contactActivityInfoList.add(contactActivity);
}
```

Comment: @njzk2 why? get String response and reparse it

Comment: @njzk2 Same thing is available for custom deserializer with JsonArray.java from Gson package. You can't manage it well without custom deserializer I think, just make the map and iterate through the keys

Comment: In most cases, retrofit uses an object mapper (often gson) so you don't have to handle the actual body of your response yourself.

Comment: Yes, a custom deserializer would make sense to do what you suggest here.

Comment: @njzk2 There is no method to iterate through the keys in the gson's JsonElement

Comment: Which makes sense, because a JsonElement is not necessarily a JsonObject. On `JsonObject`, however, there is a method to iterate on the entries.

Answer (score -4):

Using a tool like GsonFormat ([Android studio plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7654?pr=)), this is the class that maps your json:

```
public class YourClassName {

/**
 * name : name1
 * description : desc1
 */

private List<XxxEntity> xxx;
/**
 * name : name2
 * description : desc2
 */

private List<YyyEntity> yyy;
/**
 * name : name3
 * description : desc3
 */

private List<ZzzEntity> zzz;

public void setXxx(List<XxxEntity> xxx) {
    this.xxx = xxx;
}

public void setYyy(List<YyyEntity> yyy) {
    this.yyy = yyy;
}

public void setZzz(List<ZzzEntity> zzz) {
    this.zzz = zzz;
}

public List<XxxEntity> getXxx() {
    return xxx;
}

public List<YyyEntity> getYyy() {
    return yyy;
}

public List<ZzzEntity> getZzz() {
    return zzz;
}

public static class XxxEntity {
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}

public static class YyyEntity {
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}

public static class ZzzEntity {
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thank you for plugin, but in this case, xxx,yyy,zzz is dinamic values, and this solution don't help

Comment: The OP says in the question "i don't know field names"

Comment: I interpreted "i don't know field names{xxx,yyy,zzz}" as "some fixed values that I don't know".